# How can you select specific Google Mock test cases/unit tests to run?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have multiple unit tests, each per class in a separate file.

One of my standard unit tests looks like this:

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

class ClassAUnitTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
    // Per-test-case set-up.
    // Called before the first test in this test case.
    // Can be omitted if not needed.
    static void SetUpTestCase() {
        //..
    }

    // Per-test-case tear-down.
    // Called after the last test in this test case.
    // Can be omitted if not needed.
    static void TearDownTestCase() {
        //..
    }

    // You can define per-test set-up and tear-down logic as usual.
    virtual void SetUp() {  }
    virtual void TearDown() {
}
    // Some expensive resource shared by all tests.
    //..
};

TEST_F(ClassAUnitTest, testCase1) {
    // Assign .. Act .. Assert.
}
```

The way I know is to place DISABLED_ in front of the test case like this:

```
TEST_F(ClassAUnitTest, DISABLED_testCase1) {
    // Assign .. Act .. Assert.
}
```

However it is very impractical to run all tests when working on one failing unit test.

I use Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 with Gmock 1.7.0.

**Question:** How can I easily select which Unit tests or specific tests to run, and which ones not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, your unit tests should be lightning fast. Otherwise people are not going to execute them.

As explained in [Selecting tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#running-a-subset-of-the-tests), you cam use `--gtest_filter=` option. In your specific case : `--gtest_filter=ClassAUnitTest.*`

Comment: Thanks, that works! Saves a lot of information! I added this argument to the command line arguments using the following steps in VS2013: Right click project in Solution Explorer -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Debugging and add '--gtest_filter=...' to Command Arguments.